# Allow the user to choose what permissions they give?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, permissions

I am developing a Facebook app and I am asking the user for quite a lot of permissions when they login. **I am referring to the user & friend permissions here**.
I would want to let the user choose what permissions are given to the app, since some of them are not essential for the app, but may be bound to some features. I would like to do this by providing some checkboxes and receiving only the permissions the user would choose to give. Or alike the extended permissions, providing a button to remove permission from the list.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Better yet, only ask for the minimal permissions at first, then, as the user wants to perform more complex actions that require additional permissions, show them the permissions dialog again only with the relevant permissions that they need. I find people are usually scared off if they see an application is requesting *everything* they can right from the word go.

Comment: @Lix What I want to do is to give the user a JSON file containing some of the profile data, they choose they would want in the JSON. Even if I choose to request the permissions after entering the app and just before actually making up the JSON, how can I let them choose what permissions to give as I described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do almost exactly what you said you want to do: before you display the facebook oauth dialog, display a form with check-boxes for permissions which are optional for your app. You can then build your permissions list from the check-boxes. Don't rely on this to turn features requiring extended permissions on and off, though, because the user can revoke those through the oauth dialog.

You've mentioned that you want to let the user choose which JSON fields are given to them. You can perform this step after the user has granted your app permissions and give them another set of check-boxes they can use to customize their data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I will do. Ask for the minimum permissions for my app and when the user wants to save the data, ask for what data to save, informing the user at the same time that permissions are required to save the data, also making the reason the permissions are required obvious.

Each time the user wants to save, although previous settings will be retained, my app will check which permissions are valid and encode only those fields in json. Also, the user will get a dialog with what data was successfully stored. (birthday, links to photos etc).
Thanks